# How to reset Heroku app and re-commit everything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku

I'm building an application which I'm also testing in Heroku. I ran into some problem today and had to rollback one commit in my local git repo, but Heroku now won't recognize my changes saying that "everything is up to date".

So, running

```
git push heroku master
```

heroku responds with

```
Everything up-to-date
```

which isn't true.

UPDATE: Things I've tried

```
git push -f heroku master
git push --force heroku master
git push heroku +master
git push --force heroku +master
```

Did some changes in the source code and then

```
git add.
git commit -a -m "Message" #(Then this commit shows in my git explorer)
git push heroku master #Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: How did you 'rollback' a commit?

Comment: I moved the HEAD back to a non-broken commit with git reset to a commit id that works correctly

Comment: Are you sure that you had *master* checked out when you reset? It sounds like maybe you are on some other branch or have a detached HEAD. What does `git branch` say?

Comment: it says (no branch) master =)

Comment: what does `git branch -r` show?

Comment: (no branch) is a red flag. I think you're still pushing the same unmodified master. git is right. Everything's up to date. If the code you're looking at now is what you want to push to Heroku, you could make it a real branch using "git branch -b patch" then push it using "git push heroku +patch:master"

Comment: Sorry, I meant "git checkout -b patch"

Comment: Thank you guys, both @oma and @Rob Davis were in the right path. I've solved it

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Sounds weird. Maybe try pushing a different branch would do?

```
git branch production
git checkout production
#do some code changes
git commit -am "some desperate code changes to try fix heroku"
git push heroku production:master
```

Creating a new production branch is what I want you to test. Besides, it's nice to have a production branch that you can use to deploy.

If it doesn't work, then I think the problem runs deeper and you need help from heroku.

EDIT: 
Add the *heroku releases addon* too. Rolling back is as easy as `heroku rollback`

Comment: thank you for the advice. I'm new to the Rails + git + heroku development so all advice is appreciated. I'll try and get back asap

Comment: This solved it. Apparently my git HEAD was in no branch. Creating a new branch and commiting it to Heroku solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm happy you solved it. Both @Rob Davis and @Chris Johnsen was on to the solution, suspecting some local git mishap. I share credit with them!

Comment: I had the same problem, caused by using git reset and push --force. This solution works. I didn't even have to create a new branch, just git push heroku [current_branch]:master.

Comment: If your head is no branch then: 'git checkout master', make a new branch (instructions are printed by git), 'git merge new_branch', 'git push heroku master' should fix it. Could you update your answer to mention that please, as it's the quickest solution I think.

Comment: This is also useful if you're in a branch and pushing to a staging server: `[rewrite] $ git push staging rewrite:master`

Answer (score 48):

This doesn't work in all situations, but if your local repo has diverged from the Heroku repo such that git can't figure out how to reconcile the two -- like if you rebased your local branch after it was pushed to Heroku -- you can force a push by putting a plus sign + before the ref, like this:

```
git push heroku +master
```

It may not work in your case, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Still replying with everything-up-to-date =/

Comment: I ended up having to do `git push heroku +production:master`

Comment: Didn't work as of today. It just created a branch called +master.

Answer (score 26):

This worked for me (from https://coderwall.com/p/okrlzg):

1. Run `heroku plugins:install https://github.com/lstoll/heroku-repo.git`
2. `heroku repo:reset -a APPNAME`

From there, the git repository has been "reset".  Next, run:

1. `git push heroku master -a APPNAME`

to seed the git repository and re-deploy your app.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me in a NodeJS app. My git didn't recognise the `-a` flag though.

Comment: I had a problem with submodules, and this is also the only thing that worked. Pretty sure `-a APPNAME` is an error though, that's a Heroku flag, not a Git one.

Comment: This would remove the existing app from Heroku, which would mean that my production database that the current Heroku app is maintaining, would be lost in this process. Correct?

Answer (score 10):

Supposing you rolled back one commit you remotely did, that previously existed. I think you should make:

```
git merge heroku/master
```

If you just want to go forward

or:

```
git push --force heroku master
```

if you want to push that change

Comment: merge returns "Already up to date" and push with --force returns the same message as my question.I even tried to do a small change and commit to my local git repo but still Heroku says that everything is up to date

Comment: The OP clearly doesn't want the first answer, since that will just fast-forward to the state before he reset.  Doing that merge would then explain why `git push --force heroku master`, which *should* be the right answer, will produce the `Everything up-to-date` error.  However, that @bruno077 says that even after creating a new commit on `master` the `git push --force heroku master` gives `Everything up-to-date` is really strange.

Comment: ... are you really in that branch?

Answer (score 4):

I once had a similar problem and solved it by changing one char in my code and running git add/commit/push again. I imagine you've already tried that though.

Don't break the app, just add a comment to a CSS file or something and see if that does the trick

good luck

Comment: This is what I find to be very strange. I've tried this too and the heroku repo insists that everything is up to date. This is way I'm sure this behavior is unexpected. Is there a way to delete everything from the remote repo and recommit everything?

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem and solved it by

Git push origin HEAD:master

For you

Git push heroku HEAD:master

Answer (score 0):

After a while I came up to use rake task like this one [deploy.rake](https://gist.github.com/sseletskyy/9248357)

It will standardize and speed up deployment especially when migrations should be implemented

```
puts `git push -f git@heroku.com:#{APP}.git #{current_branch}`
```

As you see, option **--force** (or **-f**) is used for any push in order to ignore any conflicts with heroku's git repo

But I don't recommend it for newcomers :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried all the suggestions and didnot help. I had to run assets precompile locally and push, even though I did `heroku run rake assets:precompile`.

```
rake assets:precompile
git add .
git commit -am "local assets precompile"
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score -1):

Your heroku app will automatically reset when you upload a new version (slug) that boots.  If the change you app in a way that makes it not boot, your apps dynos will continue to run the old version.

In other words, when you deploy your app, it loads the slug (new source code) into a new dyno, and if the dyno loads the app properly, it will have that dyno replace the current dynos running your app.

This might be your problem in not seeing any change...

If you have logs from the `git push heroku` please post them.

Edit:
`git reset` deals with the git indexes and not the working tree or current branch.

You have to them checkout the commit you reset to actually change the files--  how this interacts with heroku, I'm not so sure (never having rolled back a deploy to heroku yet, fingers crossed), but hope it helps.  Maybe try doing a `git push heroku` after your checkout?

Comment: Yes, this is the behavior I'm expecting. But when trying to push to heroku, heroku responds "everything-up-to-date". I'll rephrase my question