# Over-write app on Heroku with new app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku, cedar

I had an app up on Heroku with an app name I like but with a codebase I don't intend on using. I renamed the app for the project I don't want. I then pushed to Cedar with the new app I'm working on and explicitly declared the name of the project I want using the original app name which I stopped working on. Now when I go to that app name I only see the old app even though I pushed the new up up there. What do I do to get the new app I'm working on to work with the app name I like?

I'm assuming I have to manually delete everything on Heroku and then just do a "git push heroku master" again and everything will be fine but since I'm still new to all this I'd like to know what the proper procedure is.

Thank you.

```
Here is what I mean:
http://AppNameILike.heroku.com
#rename it to:
http://AppNameIlike-OLD.heroku.com
#create new heroku app with new project (notice recycling the name I like):
http://AppNameILike.heroku.com
#This new app still shows my old app
```

Comment: have you changed the git remote to heroku to point to the new name/app?

Comment: not sure. how do i do this? when i created the new app i did: "heroku create --stack cedar" then "git push heroku master" and then "heroku rename AppNameILike"

Comment: If you go to the application directory and use the following command:
>git remote show heroku. Than can you see that the Fetch and Push URL are something like git@heroku.com:new_name.git ?

Comment: yes i can. has the name i specified.

Comment: Are you sure the subdomain DNS is pointing at the correct app?

Comment: @iWasRobbed no i'm not sure. how do i verify?

Comment: Well, if you have setup a subdomain on your main domain like, http://subdomain.mydomain.com then you must have done that in the DNS settings.  Read this for more information: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains.  If you meant to say that you just created an app on Heroku like http://myapp.heroku.com then that is a different story altogether and you did not create that subdomain, Heroku did.  You need to clarify

Comment: @iwasrobbed heroku created the subdomain.

Comment: Ok, I reworded your question to clarify that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used the heroku rename command?

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps

```
$ heroku rename newname
http://newname.heroku.com/ | git@heroku.com:newname.git
Git remote heroku updated
```

When you changed the subdomain of a heroku app, you change the git push url (i.e. the heroku git remote). Therefore you also need to use the heroku rename command for having a correct git "connection" to heroku.

Comment: yes, i did use "heroku rename AppNameILike" and that's where I am now.

Comment: The renaming process is correct but sometimes the remote heroku repo doesn't update properly because it thinks it's up-to-date when it's not. You have to push it a different branch locally and then you can switch back to master (or whichever your default repo is). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104258/how-to-reset-heroku-app-and-re-commit-everything