# Fail to deploy to Heroku: Argument list too long - bin/receive_untrusted

Tags: heroku

When I try to update my Java app on Heroku it fails with a "Argument list too long - bin/receive_untrusted". This happens before the actual build process starts and it's the only error that I'm getting. Of course it build perfect locally..

```
Counting objects: 95506, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (28630/28630), done.
Writing objects: 100% (95506/95506), 16.95 MiB | 2.82 MiB/s, done.
Total 95506 (delta 42943), reused 94815 (delta 42643)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: Build stream timed out, reverting to polling...
remote: 
remote: Build output:
remote: Argument list too long - bin/receive_untrusted
remote: !   Push rejected to xxxxx.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/xxxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] develop -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/xxxxx.git'
```

Comment: Is this persistently happening, or was it a one-time event?

Comment: Apparently it only happened on that day (consistently). It seems to be fixed although nothing was changed on my side. Odd

Comment: I work at Heroku, and I've asked around with some folks internally. We haven't been able to figure out what caused it. Please open a support ticket if you see if again. https://help.heroku.com/ thanks!

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with my node.js app. No one found an explanation as to why?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that fixed it for me was resetting the Git repo in Heroku and pushing it from scratch, a described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20134575/988704).